# 500 (Internal Server Error) after 60 sec of transaction on WAS

Tags: http, websphere-7

I have same **EAR** file deployed on 2 different instances of **WAS7**. It runs fine one one server instance, while on other instance, the server returns 500 (Internal Server Error) when transaction time exceeds 60 seconds.

Application runs fine on both the server when transaction time is less than 60 sec.

General transaction properties in `Application servers > server1 > Transaction service` are identical on both the server instance.

I believe its not a coding issue and in that case its something related to  server settings.

Comment: Add full stack trace, it is too little info to tell something more than to double check Transaction service settings.

Comment: There is actually no error message at the server side. After 60 sec of transaction server returns status 500 to browser. I believe it is related to ServerIOTimeout property in the IHS Plugin component.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you are correct. Look at the definition from documentation:

> The `ServerIOTimeout` specifies whether there is a time limit for how
>   long the plug-in waits to send a request to or receive a response from
>   the application server.

The default value for v7 for this parameter is 60 seconds, which is too low for your application. You have to change it.
You can just edit it in `plugin-cfg.xml` (see details in the first link).
However if you often regenerate your it, it will be better to change it in the server configuration ( `Servers > Server Types > WebSphere application servers > server_name`, and then, in the `Additional Properties` section, click `Web server plug-in properties` - details in the second link).
The third link gives you some more details how different values of the plugin parameters affects request handling and retries.

See also:

- [plugin-cfg.xml details](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.nd.doc/ae/rwsv_plugincfg.html?lang=en)
- [Application Server property settings for a web server plug-in](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.nd.doc/ae/uwsv_plugin_props5.html?lang=en)
- [Webserver Plugin configuration practices](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21450051)